# Literature in the 80's SELECT from NOBEL SQLZOO Unknown column in field list [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello fellow programmers,

I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
SELECT yr, subject, winner
FROM world
WHERE yr >=1980 AND yr <=1989 AND subject = 'Literature'
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Unknown column 'yr' in 'field list'
```

I have looked up walkthroughs and they all say that this code is correct. I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here but I can't figure out what. Perhaps you can help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It seems there is no column named yr in your table world. Can you please share the table structure?

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand.  It seems very clear.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of your table "world"s structure?

Comment: @Neox. **No!** [no screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), create table statement please.

Comment: @HoneyBadger it is a screenshot of his table that I'm asking, not of his code. Anything that helps us see what's wrong in the table, and a screenshot for **this** case is just fine. This is not code. But yeah, something else then, if he can.

Comment: Assuming you are using [this](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial), why did you change the table? You should just select from nobel: `SELECT yr, subject, winner FROM nobel WHERE yr >=1980 AND yr <=1989 AND subject = 'Literature'`

Comment: @HoneyBadger ugh, yes, it's supposed to be nobel instead of world. I figured it was something stupid like that. Thanks!